# curl request through TLS v1.0

Tags: php, curl

Using below code to send request over TLS v1.0.

```
$url = "https://example.com";
$input_segment = "";

$data = array('InputSegments'=>$input_segment, 'cmdSubmit'=>'Submit');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, "443");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                                        ));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$err_no = curl_errno($ch);
$err = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($response);
```

**ERROR**

> Error #:SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104

It looks like still using SSL. How to send curl request over TLSv1.0 in PHP?

Comment: LMGTFY: https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/1689

Comment: try using the constant `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0` instead of 4. Also set CURLOPT_USE_SSL to force the usage of the TLS (or SSL) requested and fail otherwise.

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai: Server issue means from third party side or something I need to fix it from my side?

Comment: @LordNeo: Updated the request with these 2 lines: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, "TLS");` still same result

Comment: may be your sever, may be the other side. As the ticket on github says - not really sure.

Comment: try to run curl from command line using --tlsv1

Comment: @LordNeo: I think there is a problem with PHP only.

Comment: @RonakPatel is there a big urgency to do request over TLS 1.0 ? Cuz server part may not use that version.

Comment: @RonakPatel btw have You tried to use Guzzle? Check this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33134274/how-do-we-specify-tls-ssl-options-in-guzzle

Comment: @num8er: Its a requirement from our third party provider. What do you mean by server part may not use that version?

Comment: @RonakPatel for example when I setup certificate and ssl in nginx I always define latest tls version for security.

Comment: @num8er: We are using apache. Do you know how to check it and enable it for this feature?

Comment: apache `ssl.conf` setup is like this: `SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -SSLv2`

Comment: @RonakPatel need to see php configs and etc...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155788/discussion-between-ronak-patel-and-num8er).

Answer (score 0):

to force TLS 1.0, i think it's sufficient to set CURLOPT_SSLVERSION to CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0